# Как использовать утилиты kill \ orakill для уничтожения сессии?

Tags: sql, oracle

Команды:

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#';
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#' IMMEDIATE;
ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION 'sid,serial#';
ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION 'sid,serial#' IMMEDIATE;
```

не позволяют снять **быстро** сессии выполняющие излишне длительный запрос.

В [анналах sql.ru](http://www.sql.ru/forum/842542/raznica-mezhdu-alter-system-kill-session-i-alter-system-disconnect-session) нашёл, что можно гарантированно убить сессию Oracle с помощью утилиты командной строки:

> kill/orakill (nix/win) позволяет достичь результата -- [сообщение *dbms_photoshop*](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=842542&msg=10495853)

Но как ими пользоваться?

@Viktorov привёл варианты использования. Всё понятно. Но запрос:

```
SELECT S.SID  as ORACLE_SID,
       P.SPID as SPID,
       S.OSUSER,
       S.PROGRAM
FROM   V$PROCESS P,
       V$SESSION S
WHERE  P.ADDR = S.PADDR;
```

на моей базе данных выдаёт один и тот же `SPID` для множества сессий. Но я хочу убить лишь конкретную. Как быть в этом случае?

Так опрашиваю конфигурацию процессов:

```
select server, count(*) from v$session group by server;

DEDICATED   34
NONE        269
SHARED      13

select count(*) from v$session where server='DEDICATED' and osuser!='oracle';

0
```

Comment: "один и тот же SPID для множества сессий" - у вас сконфигурнрован не выделенный сервер?

Comment: @0xdb этого я не знаю. Сейчас подучу матчасть и отвечу.

Comment: Хорошо, для поиска:  dedicated or shared server.

Comment: @0xdb ну на асктом пишут "All databases ALWAYS run in "dedicated" mode. It is not really even a "mode", it is a method of connecting. "      "You can see how *sessions* are connected via V$SESSION "       Я добавил в конец вопроса итоги из V$SESSION

Comment: У вас shared server, поэтому, если вернуться к первоночальному вопросу,  на системном уровне убить одну сессию не получиться. Ничего страшного не случиться, просто все сессии на одном сервере будут убиты и открытые трансакции будут откачены.

Comment: @0xdb будете ответ публиковать или дополню ответ IDrakonl ?

Comment: @0xdb так как с режимами не разобрался, задал новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752361/dedicated-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-shared-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: сейчас не могу ответы давать, т.к. в отпуске на мобиле, через неделю вернусь, тогда дополню, поправлю.

Comment: Я дополнил связаный вопрос примером, есть ли какое либо недопонимание в текущем вопросе?

Comment: @0xdb в текущем всё ясно, спасибо. Будете ответ публиковать или дополню ответ IDrakonl (Viktorov) ?

Comment: А чем дополните, ведь всё ясно? Что то я не совсем уже теме.

Comment: 0xdb, ну должно быть ясно в ответе, а не в комментариях

Comment: Комментариев тут чуть меньше, чем томик "Война и мир". Вы напишите коротко, что не хватает и @Viktorov поправит вопрос. С моей   точки зрения,  "PS" можно убрать. В остальном прямой ответ на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала надо определить сессию, которую собираемся завершить:

```
SELECT S.SID  as ORACLE_SID,
       P.SPID as SPID,
       S.OSUSER,
       S.PROGRAM
FROM   V$PROCESS P,
       V$SESSION S
WHERE  P.ADDR = S.PADDR;
```

**Windows:**
подставляем полученные значения из запроса ранее

```
orakill ORACLE_SID SPID
```

***NIX:**

```
kill -9 spid
```

**PS**

Хочу обратить внимание, что использование `alter system kill` или `alter system disconnect` предпочтительнее, чем `kill/orakill`.

Как выяснилось из комментариев, данный способ годится только для сессий подключенных к выделенному (Dedicated) серверному процессу. При подключении к распределенному (Shared) серверному процессу завершить одну отдельную сессию с помощью утилит `kill\orakill` не получится.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69527/discussion-on-answer-by-ldrakonl----kill-orakill--).