# Конфигурация dedicated или shared сервер. Каковы критерии выбора?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Какую конфигурацию серверa выбрать - dedicated или shared?

Каковы критерии выбора и как переключиться с dedicated на shared и наоборот во время эксплуатации, если ранее был сделан неправильный выбор?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle БД создаёт серверный процесс для обработки запросов пользовательских процессов подключенных к определённой инстанции.

Серверный процесс: на *NIX это процесс на системном уровне (начиная с 12c может бытъ сконфигурирован как поток). Под WIN это всегда поток.

Пользовательский процесс: это клиентское приложение, выполняющееся на удалённой системе или на системе, где установлена БД, и содержащее один или более запросов на подключение типа (зависит от ЯП) `OracleDriver.connect (params)`.

Серверный процесс может бытъ:

- dedicated (выделенный), обслуживает только один пользовательский процесс
- shared (распределённый), который обслуживает несколько пользовательских процессов (ранее известный как MTS - multi-threded-server)

По умолчанию всегда сконфигурирован dedicated сервер. Для конфигурации распределённого сервера необходимо изменение параметров инициализации в SPFILE: `shared_servers=3`, где 3 кол-во процессов. Или коммандой:

```
SQL> alter system set shared_servers=3 scope=both;
```

Если уже сконфигурирован распределённый сервер, то для подсоединения как выделенный сервер используется сетевой параметер: `SERVER=DEDICATED`.

Критерии выбора:

- Распределённый сервер был введён в версии 7, когда системные ресурсы (в первую очередь, память) были очень дороги и этим достигалась их экономия. В настоящее время эта экономия больше не существенна. В случае выделенного сервера отпадает оверхед на респределение (dispatch) и поэтому эта конфигурация более производительна.
- Несмотря на то, что в офф. документации shared сервер всё ешё упомянут как предпочтительный, всё же конфигурация как dedicated сервер является более целесообразной в 95% случаев.
- Распределённый сервер лучше использовать, если много клиентских процессов, которые не используют постояннный коннект к БД, т.е. вызывается подключение, производится обновление одной или нескольких таблиц и далее производится явное или неявное разединение. Каждый, кто немного знаком с современными программными архитектурами, заметит, что подобный сценарий уже изжил себя.

Пример того, что будет создано на системном уровне для выделенного сервера (для лучшего понимания в [связанном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751048/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b-kill-orakill-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
select 
    s.username, s.program,  s.server, s.osuser, 
    s.process, p.spid, p.program, s.sid, s.serial#  
from v$session s
join v$process p on p.addr=s.paddr
where s.username is not null 
;

USER PROGRAM                    SERVER    OSUS PROCESS          SPID     PROGRAM                           SID    SERIAL#
---- -------------------------- --------- ---- ---------------- -------- -------------------------- ---------- ----------
DB   sqlplus.exe                DEDICATED db   14824:9844       2025     oracle@mpsrv                      137      31220
DB   sqlplus@mpsrv (TNS V1-V3)  DEDICATED db   2068             2072     oracle@mpsrv (TNS V1-V3)          135      32936
```

Где:
*process* - пользовательский процесс
*spid* - серверный процесс
*user/osuser* - имена пользователя в БД/ОС (здесь db это не database, это мои инициалы).
Первая строчка - удалённый *sqlplus*, вторая - локально на БД сервере. Обратите внимание, что локально используется *bequeath* протокол и серверный процесс непосредственный форк от пользовательского процесса, т.е. соединение без участия сетевого прослушивателя:

```
$ ps -ef | egrep "(2068|2072|2025)"
oracle    2025     1  oraclemyoradb (LOCAL=NO)
db        2068  2067  /vol/db/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/home/bin/sqlplus
oracle    2072  2068  oraclemyoradb (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))
```

Подробнее: [офф. документация](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/manproc001.htm#ADMIN11166)